# ERROR IN ORACLE WHILE EXECUTING QUERY

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute the below query and trying to get output in variable.

```
DECLARE LATESTID INT
SELECT LATESTID := ID FROM Cust_RectifiedDetails WHERE CustNo = UNIFIEDCUSTOMERNO
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

But while executing i am getting the below error :

> ```
> ORA-24344: success with compilation error
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LATESTID" when expecting one of the following:
>
>    := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
> ```

Kindly please guide me
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done using SELECT INTO
try this :

```
BEGIN
   SELECT ID INTO LATESTID  FROM Cust_RectifiedDetails WHERE CustNo = UNIFIEDCUSTOMERNO
END;
```

Don't forget the BEGIN and END; clause and a semi-colon after your INT

Answer (score 2):

After a `DECLARE` section you need a `BEGIN`.

Also, the semicolon after `INT` is missing.

You can't assign values in a select statement with a `:=`. Use `select into` instead.

Finally, an `order by` makes no sense when you `select into`. You might want to catch `too_many_values`. Alternatively, you might want to try `max()` or any of its derivatives.

```
declare
  latestid int;

begin

  select id into latestid
   from  cust_rectifieddetails
   where custno = unifiedcustomerno;

exception when to_many_values then
-- Do what you need to do.
   raise;

end;
```

Comment: Quite an explanation you gave.. :)